# How do I setContentView in a class that extends View? (Android, Java)

Tags: java, android

So I am making an android app where when you open the app, you start off in the main activity. Once you hit the play button, I made an onclick listener that sets the content view to another class that extends View. The game goes on in this class by drawing to a canvas. Once the user loses the game, I want it to reset the content view to my main activity. Is there any way to do this? Sorry if this is confusing, I am fairly new to java. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send information to another class from `MainActivity` and after returns it initialized, you can use `startActivityForResult()`, like this:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent("Example"), 1);
```

where you have to declare your intent `"Example"` in your `Manifest` file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ExecuteExample" //Here the name of the Class in which you send the information
    android:label="Example" > 

       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="Example" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So, when the user loses the game, you retrieve the new information again to the `MainActivity` with `setResult` function (from `ExecuteExample`):

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, example);
```

where `example` it's the name of the intent that you send now to `MainActivity`. How to set the information to this new Intent? Easy, just with `.putExtra()` function. Something like this:

```
example.putExtra("Score",0);
example.putExtra("Name","");
```

supossing that the values that you want to initialize are the `Score` and the `Name` of the user that played before.

Finally, you have to retrieve this information initialized from the `MainActivity` class creating a new method `onActivityResult()`:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
   if (requestCode == 1)
   {
      if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
      {

         int score = data.getIntExtra("Score");
         String name = datos.getStringExtra("Name");
      }
   }
}
```

I expect it will helps to you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to load activity? You can try with the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
```